# Make Portage install non-free software after confirmation

Tags: package-management, gentoo, free-software, portage

So, in my `make.conf` I have `ACCEPT_LICENSE="@FREE"` variable set up, but I still want to use some proprietary software. Best case scenario would be Portage warning that the software I'm going to install is not free and then ask for a confirmation to proceed. Is that possible?

Comment: BTW. I'm not sure if it shouldn't be `ACCEPT_LICENSE="-* @FREE"` - don't allow anything, allow free.

Comment: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki//etc/portage/make.conf#ACCEPT_LICENSE

Answer (score 1):

I have `ACCEPT_LICENSES="-* @FREE"`, yet sadly need some proprietary software for school once in while. I solved this using the optional file in `/etc/portage`, `package.license`, where you can instruct portage to make exceptions for certain licenses on certain packages.

The format of `package.license` is similar to `package.use`: you supply one package per line, in the format of `category/package license`. You can use `#` to start comments as well.

You can also make `/etc/portage/package.license` a directory, like the other configuration files in there. In that case, it will read all files inside this directory.

Using this configuration, when you try to install software with licenses not included in `@FREE`, portage will complain about it. It will inform you which packages require which licenses to be accepted, which you can then add to your `package.license` configuration.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add **ACCEPT_LICENSE="-* @FREE"** in the **/etc/portage/make.conf**
2. Add **ACCEPT_LICENSE="*"** in the **/etc/portage/env/accept_license.conf**

Then you can allow specific packages you want creating a file on **/etc/portage/package.env**.

E.g (**/etc/portage/package.env/non-free**):

```
<category>/<some-software> accept_license.conf
```

Comment: One may use `/etc/portage/package.license` directly, but you have to specify the exact allowed licenses.